# Separating user accounts in a wallet for a large scale web app

Tags: transactions, address, client, balance, bitcoin-core-accounts

I'm planning to implement a web platform that maintains user wallet accounts and generally acts as a web wallet. They can deposit, withdraw and transfer coins.The number of accounts should be in magnitude of thousands. I'm considering the implementation options for simulating many different web wallets inside several factual wallets. I wonder how existing services do it?

I'm aware of the following options for the implementaiton:

1. Using accounts inside wallet. Pros: wallet supports commands for checking ballance, sending from account etc. Cons:  still spends coins from general wallet, so hard to keep track of; Is deprecated; Complicated to do backups
2. Using separate private keys for each user. Not sure how to do it.
3. Keeping track of ballances and transactions inside proprietary system. Pros: no problems related to option nr. 1; Cons: Probably a hell to maintain, not even sure how to implement it;

Id love if someone could give me some advice and or share experience. What is the best option? Is there anything else I'm not considering?